# Range of adoint operator

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, operator-theory

We consider infinite dimension.

$X,Y$: Banach Spaces
$T:X→Y$ is a bounded linear operator.

I want to prove 
$(\ker\, T)^\bot = \overline {R(T^*)}$.

$(\ker\, T)^\bot = \{f\in X^*|f(x)=0\ (x\in \ker\,T) \}$

But I can't.
If you have an answer, please tell me hints.
I'm sorry my broken English,I'm Japanese.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Counterexample.** Let $\lambda\in c_0$ with non zero entries. Consider diagonal operators 
$$
T:\ell_1\to\ell_1:x\mapsto\lambda x\\
S:\ell_\infty\to\ell_\infty:x\mapsto\lambda x
$$
This is straightforward to check that $S=T^*$.
Obviously $\operatorname{Ker}(T)^\perp=\{0\}^\perp=\ell_1^*=\ell_\infty$. Since $\lambda\in c_0$ then $\operatorname{Im}(S)\subset c_0$. So 
$$
\overline{\operatorname{Im}(T^*)}=\overline{\operatorname{Im}(S)}\subset \overline{c_0}=c_0\subsetneq \ell_\infty=\operatorname{Ker}(T)^\perp
$$

**Fact.** 
$$
\overline{\operatorname{Im}(T^*)}=\operatorname{Ker}(T)^\perp
\Longleftrightarrow \operatorname{Im}(T)\text{ is closed}
$$

Comment: Thank you for your kindness.I cant believe there is a counterexample.I will try to probe the equivalent relation tomorrow.Thanks again.

Comment: @Daisuke if you are happy with this answer you can accept it by clicking checkbox under vote counts. If you want I'll post proof of equivalence later on.